# How to disable the Textbox's text encoding before saving it into the data base?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-web-developer

I entered the text "J&K"(Without Cotes) in my StateCode textbox and saved it into database(SqlServer). But it saved as J & amp; K. So m not able to fetch the data saved, with J&K(Primery key). How can I disable encoding of text before saving it to database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [HttpUtility.HtmlDecode Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k.aspx) to remove the encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Server.HtmlEncode("YourTextWith<and>Characters")` for this activity.

wrap your output text within it.

Or,

This can also be helpfull>>

```
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTextArea textBox = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTextArea();
textBox.Value = "j&k";
```

Hope its helpful.